# How do install Scipy version 1.11.1?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I am trying to pip install the latest version of scipy (1.11.1)so that I can access the CensoredData function. I've tried everything that I could think of but can't seem to install the package.

If for some reason I remain unable to install this package, the problem that I am facing in my research is trying to fit data that has been logarithmically binned to different models/probability distributions. If anyone knows about other tools/packages for fitting data that has been logarithmically binned to different models that would also be very helpful.

The SciPy website says that 1.11.1 is the most recent version and that it should be available via 'pip install --user scipy' however, that only installs version 1.10.0 which I already have.

I've also tried to install the latest version directly from GitHub but that too seems to fail.

Comment: You haven't posted a single error...

Comment: `python -m pip install scipy` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `pip install --user --upgrade scipy` for the newest version (actually 1.11.2). For a specific version, you can do `pip install --user scipy==1.11.1`. You will likely be told "Requirement already satisfied" if you just do `pip install --user scipy`, as it finds that it is already installed.